# Golang FileServer check progress

Tags: http, go, fileserver

I have created a simple FileServer using GoLang

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func loggingHandler(h http.Handler) http.Handler {
    return http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        log.Println(r.Method, r.RemoteAddr,r.URL.Path)
        h.ServeHTTP(w, r)
    })
}

func main() {
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", loggingHandler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("/directory/subdir/"))))
}
```

Now I am looking for a way to check if file is properly downloaded by host, or monitor how many bytes are arleady downloaded.
Unfortunetly I am unable to find any hints on the internet or if it is even posibble.
Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Is it possible to verify the correctness of downloading the file from the server?

Comment: Are you asking how to monitor progress on the client or the server?

Comment: I want to monitor progress on the server

Answer (score 1):

You can provide your implementation of `FileSystem` with a progress counter to the `FileServer`.

Example:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

type fileWithProgress struct {
    http.File
    size         int64
    downloaded   int64
    lastReported int64
    name         string
    client       string
}

func (f *fileWithProgress) Read(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    n, err = f.File.Read(p)
    f.downloaded += int64(n)
    f.lastReported += int64(n)
    if f.lastReported > 1_000_000 { // report every 1e6 bytes
        println("client:", f.client, "file:", f.name, "downloaded:", f.downloaded*100/f.size, "%")
        f.lastReported = 0
    }
    return n, err
}

func (f *fileWithProgress) Seek(offset int64, whence int) (int64, error) {
    f.downloaded = 0 // reset content detection read if no content-type specified
    return f.File.Seek(offset, whence)
}

func (f *fileWithProgress) Close() error {
    println("client:", f.client, "file:", f.name, "done", f.downloaded, "of", f.size, "bytes")
    return f.File.Close()
}

type dirWithProgress struct {
    http.FileSystem
    client string
}

func (d *dirWithProgress) Open(name string) (http.File, error) {
    println("open:", name, "for the client:", d.client)
    f, err := d.FileSystem.Open(name)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    st, err := f.Stat()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return &fileWithProgress{File: f, size: st.Size(), name: st.Name(), client: d.client}, nil
}

func fileServer(fs http.FileSystem) http.Handler {
    f := func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        progressDir := dirWithProgress{FileSystem: fs, client: r.RemoteAddr}
        http.FileServer(&progressDir).ServeHTTP(w, r)
    }
    return http.HandlerFunc(f)
}

func main() {
    dir := http.Dir(".")
    fs := fileServer(dir)
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.ListenAndServe("127.0.0.1:8080", nil)
}
```

Comment: The chief problem is that such implementation is next to useless since an HTTP server is (typically) able to serve many clients in parallel, and I see no obvious way to correlate incoming requests with opened files. Do you know of any?

Comment: @kostix, yes middleware over fileServer to capture user info.

Comment: The question is not how to capture the user info but rather how to correlate it with the file being served (and whose serving progress is being tracked).

Comment: updated with reporting the progress per client